# Print JSON results to screen

Tags: android, json, http-post

I have this HTTP/JSON code that should retrieve data from a database but how do I go about printing it to the screen. If you need any extra code, let me know. Thanks

```
String result = "";
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","Badminton"));

//http post
try{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myurl.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
}
catch(Exception e1){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e1.toString());
}

//convert response to string
try{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}

is.close();
result=sb.toString();
}

catch(Exception e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}

//parse json data
try{
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
{
JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
Log.i("log_tag","type: "+json_data.getInt("id"));
}
}

catch(Exception e)
{
Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

So how would I go about printing the data I have received from the PHP file to the screen, I will do more stuff with it later

Comment: Where do you want to display on the screen? ListView, GridView, TextView or else?

Comment: anywhere at the moment aha

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in glancing at the JSON and if it is small enough you can toast it..

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If you want to see the entire json you can put it into a `TextView` and use the [toString](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28int%29) method of a JSON object to pretty print it.

Comment: Cheers, I just wanted to know which variable stores the JSON data from the PHP file as the 'change textview code' is already set up

Comment: The output is stored in a variable called result. String result = "";. Is the java snippet you posted not your code ?

Comment: i was following a tutorial but got confused aha. I thought it was call result, but couldn't be sure as I couldnt think how to use it

Comment: Because I tried putting a toast underneath the result=sb.toString(); code using the result rsult to show the data but it didnt show anything so the variable is empty....

Comment: That is another problem entirely. May be you never get the response due to an exception. Raise a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just quickly display it to the user you can use a `Toast`. More on Toasts can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGH_SHORT).show();
```

If you want to display it in a specific view, e.g. a `TextView` on screen you need to find that view and just set the text you want diplayed.

```
TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.where_im_displaying_text);
v.setText(text);
```

If you're trying to do something else let us know so we can help.

Comment: Hey, cheers for the reply. Which variable is all the data stored to?

Comment: In the toast the text you want to display goes where it says "text". Same for the TextView. You can put in whatever variable you want there so long as its a string. Just extract the text you need from the JSON and insert it.

Comment: I just wanted to know what is the variable called in the code in the question that the data from the php code is saved to... as i have change textview code already set up

Comment: Oh - that's not what you question asked. That's hard for me to answer since I don't know where the information you're trying to reach is located. I am gussing its located within the JSONObject you have extracted in the code. Since you never actually extract a string from that JSONObject there is no string value to display. You need to use String text = json_data.getString("title"). If it is just the server response you want to display - it looks like it is stored to result, which is the result of your StringBuilder.